# Dynamic AngularJS disappears when using $timeout

Tags: jquery, angularjs, dynamic, timeout

I am totally new to AngularJs but I have managed to learn the basics of the framework. However, I have recently encountered an exotic behavior from AngularJs ,which is known for being dynamic.

Here is the issue:

**Index.html**

```
<div ng-controller="userClick as clk">
 <div id="square1">{{ clk.board[0] }}</div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
app.controller('userClick', function($timeout) {
   this.board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

$timeout(reset, 1000);
function reset (){
 this.board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
 console.log(this.board); //returns ^^ (empty array)
}
```

It is expected that when the user clicks on one of the *squares* on the page, that a function is executed and everything goes well. But when I try to use the **$timeout** function to delay the response for a second, the array **this.board** gets reset successfully to an empty one but the div there with the id **square1** doesn't gets empty back again.

It seems that something causes Angular to be static at this point that I don't get.

**Note:** It is a Tic Tac Toe game.

Comment: `this` inside reset() function isn't same `this` as outside function. Has nothing to do with angular , is a javascript scope issue

Comment: So how to change the board array with the correct scope ??

Comment: in controller store reference to `this` in variable and use that variable inside function instead of `this`. See https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md#style-y032

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a lot it finally worked !!

Answer (score 1):

You could declare the `reset` function as a controller function and use that instead.

```
app.controller('userClick', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {
    var ctrl = this;
    ctrl.board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];

    ctrl.reset = function() {
       ctrl.board = ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''];
       console.log(ctrl.board); 
    };
    $timeout(ctrl.reset, 1000);

    // Rest of your controller logic
}]);
```

Comment: shouldn't set `ctrl` as global variable

Comment: @charlietfl why? I am sure I am not going to create another controller or a variable with the same name

Comment: @YEAMA because it is a terrible practice that can lead to all sorts of hard to find bugs. Should always declare variables using `var`

Comment: @sebastianForsberg What if I wanted to change this **ctrl.board** array from outside the controller ??